# Универсальный метод для чтения данных из БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

У меня есть база данных в MS SQL Server. В ней есть различные таблицы. Я хочу соотнести объекты (строки) в этих таблицах с определенными классами в самой программе. Можно ли как-то сделать универсальный метод для чтения данных из БД и создания на основе этих данных объектов? Или же придётся реализовывать метод чтения для каждого класса по-своему?

Comment: Можно и что. Вы думаете универсальный скрипт будет очень хорошим? У вас будет запрос к базе прямой. И.е указали таблицу и вызываете команду заполнить. А вот сериализовать в нужный класс будите руками.

Comment: Откройте для себя ORM, например Entity Framework или Dapper (в зависимости от ваших нужд)